# Google API Lodging Properties

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I'm trying to figure out the new GMB Lodging API but I'm having trouble with two of the methods they provide.

For locations its supposed to get and update Lodging properties however I can't seem to get or update any of the lodging for a test business -> https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/lodging/rest/v1/locations.

As for locations lodging the getGoogleUpdated seems to be working on my end which is why I think that there is something wrong with the API itself https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/lodging/rest/v1/locations.lodging.

Has anybody started working with getLodging and updateLodging?